# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator (6.5.0) Clustering with Load Balancer

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I developed 4 proxy services using WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.5.0.

So i need to implement clustering with load balancer on these services to test of their Performance (Stress)

*Note : **I'm implementing on my localhost (Windows 10)***

```
I followed below guide :
```

https://medium.com/@snsavithrik1/wso2-ei-worker-manager-clustering-on-a-single-machine-dae1161bcb78

But it seems not working, gives me, no response

[image]

**it is my management node axis.xml config :**

```
 <parameter name="localMemberHost">mgt.esb.wso2.com</parameter>
  <parameter name="localMemberPort">4100</parameter>
  <member>
    <hostName>esb.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4200</port>
  </member>
```

**carbon.xml (Management node - First node) :**

```
   <!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->
    <HostName>esb.wso2.com</HostName>
    <MgtHostName>mgt.esb.wso2.com</MgtHostName>
```

**Worker node : Axis.XML**

```
<parameter name="localMemberHost">esb.wso2.com</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberPort">4200</parameter>
  <member>
    <hostName>mgt.esb.wso2.com</hostName>
    <port>4100</port>
  </member>
```

**carbon.xml - Worker node (second node) :**

```
<HostName>esb.wso2.com</HostName>
```

**system32/driver/hosts config :**

```
    127.0.0.1          esb.wso2.com
    127.0.0.1          mgt.esb.wso2.com
#   127.0.0.1          esb.wso2.com
#   127.0.0.1          mgt.esb.wso2.com
#   ::1                esb.wso2.com
```

Help me please!
Regards,
Thanks

Comment: you need no cluster for stress / performance tests. The cluster is used only for managing singleton tasks, such as message processors, scheduled tasks, ..

Comment: got you, but i need to

Answer (score 0):

Your hostnames are resolved resulting to the same localhost IP address, so no new member is detected

Some things to improve / fix:

1. Use IP addresses for clustering (and not 127.0.0.1), it is so as well in the blog you've linked
2. you can set the members sections to contain all member hosts

example of axis2.xml

`<parameter name="localMemberHost">192.168.100.12</parameter>
  <parameter name="localMemberPort">4100</parameter>
  <members>
    <member>
      <hostName>192.168.100.12</hostName>
      <port>4100</port>
    </member>
    <member>
      <hostName>192.168.100.13</hostName>
      <port>4100</port>
    </member>
  <members>`

I have very bad feeling that each cluster member is recognized based on its IP address so you may have an issue to set it on a single 'localhost'. Test it and see.

Note - personally I use Docker to test / deploy / manage multiple instances, you will get cleaner separation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
i have done as you said here then when i send to proxy service(deployed on Manager Node) it only receives request count on Manager Node, 
I expect that when i send to manager node it handles request using Other nodes(Worker), i think mine is implemented without Load Balancer ?

Comment: I do not know that 's(clustered deployment) working properly or not

Comment: @xxcaptain You may have misunderstood what clustering in wso2 does. It's really only about coordination. The clustering doesn't provide any load balancing. You need a separate load balancer in front of the services to distribute workload. Management/worker nodes make sense only for rsync based replication for deployed artifacts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
With clustered deployment (Manager & Worker Node), if i deploy proxy service on one instance(EI1), Then
it will be deployed automatically on other instance(EI2) right ? 
Because each node joined in each other

Comment: @xxcaptain `will be deployed automatically.. ` please read the docs https://docs.wso2.com/m/mobile.action#page/85376922 it is not automatically. You need to share the deployment storage (for active-active) or rsync the artifacts (for manager/worker). Do not make assumptions, read the docs

Comment: thanks , `INFO - WKABasedMembershipScheme Member joined [9de6b74e-f6c2-4728-900d-ed083f5e5f3a]: esb.wso2.com/192.168.137.2:4200`

this log prints in console of Manager Node - why do port number and domain name are duplicated, i configured windows/host 
 **`192.168.137.2          esb.wso2.com
 192.168.137.1       mgt.esb.wso2.com`**

**esb.wso2.com** - worker node